# How do I use jQuery UI draggable to set values in forms?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I can't seem to find any tutorial on Google regarding this, but I've seen people do it in some websites.

I'm trying to create a form where my users can drag and drop products into their shopping list but I have no idea how to get jQuery UI's draggable to set the values for that specific form field once it has been dropped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [**drop** event](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop) that is fired when you drop something:

> **drop( event, ui )**
>   Triggered when an accepted draggable is dropped on the droppable (based on the `tolerance` option).

So all you need to do is listen for the drop event and update something (such as an `<input type="hidden">`) in the form as needed. You could use a data attribute on the draggable to identify the product elements:

```
<div data-product="pancakes">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

and then do something like this to update your form:

```
$("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        // ui.draggable is the jQuery object for the thing being dragged (and
        // hence the thing being dropped).
        $('input').val(ui.draggable.data('product'));
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/6Cy97/

Comment: Woah thanks for pointing me towards jsfiddle! I totally forgot about this useful app. I'm almost there thanks to you! 

One thing I'm still missing is how do I sort multiple fields in multiple droppable divs? Take a look at the fiddle I've created (only the html is correct, the javascript obviously isn't working): http://jsfiddle.net/imjp/5NWAQ/

Comment: @imjp: Yeah, jsfiddle is pretty cool. You want to select "jQuery" in the "Choose Framework" panel in the sidebar and then check the "jQuery UI" toggle underneath that: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/5NWAQ/3/ . Your store also sells pancakes now :)

Comment: I've updated it: http://jsfiddle.net/imjp/5NWAQ/4/ -- I've also created a new StackOverflow question regarding this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677068/how-to-sort-and-create-multiple-text-fields-with-jquery-uis-droppable