# How to sort and create multiple text fields with jQuery UI's droppable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

**Scenario:** I'd like my users to be able to to create a shopping list by dragging products into a droppable & sortable list. Depending on the location of the product on the list, and the value of the product, the text fields for this form must be populated.

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/imjp/5NWAQ/1/

For instance:

- Orange
- Apple
- Banana

Generates the following values in my form's fields (based of course on the `data-product attribute`):

- item_1: orange
- item_2: apple
- item_3: banana

If I move the apple up, the fields must also update this.

Here's some html i've put together:

```
<div class="demo">

<div id="products">
<h1 class="ui-widget-header">Products</h1>    
<div id="catalog">
    <h3><a href="#">T-Shirts</a></h3>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li data-product="Lolcat Shirt">Lolcat Shirt</li>
            <li data-product="Cheezeburger Shirt">Cheezeburger Shirt</li>
            <li data-product="Buckit Shirt">Buckit Shirt</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#">Bags</a></h3>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Zebra Striped</li>
            <li>Black Leather</li>
            <li>Alligator Leather</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#">Gadgets</a></h3>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>iPhone</li>
            <li>iPod</li>
            <li>iPad</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="cart">
<h1 class="ui-widget-header">Shopping Cart</h1>
<div class="ui-widget-content">
    <ol>
        <li class="placeholder">Add your items here</li>
    </ol>
</div>
</div>
<div id="cart">
<h1 class="ui-widget-header">Shopping Cart</h1>
<div class="ui-widget-content">
    <ol>
        <li class="placeholder">Add your items here</li>
    </ol>
</div>
</div>


<div id="list_1" style="clear: both; float: left;">
  <h3>List 1</h3>
<input id="list_1_item_1" type="text">
<input id="list_1_item_2" type="text">
</div>

 <div id="list_2" style="clear: both; float: left;">
      <h3>List 2</h3>
  <input id="list_2_item_1" type="text">
 <input id="list_2_item_2" type="text">
 </div>
 </div><!-- End demo -->
```

javascript (Keep in mind that the javascript code is not working like i want it to, it updates all of the fields with the same value) :

```
$( "#catalog" ).accordion();
    $( "#catalog li" ).draggable({
        appendTo: "body",
        helper: "clone"
    });
    $( "#cart ol" ).droppable({
        activeClass: "ui-state-default",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
        accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this ).find( ".placeholder" ).remove();
            console.log(ui.draggable.length);
    $('#list_1_item_1').val(ui.draggable.data('product')); 
    $('#list_1_item_2').val(ui.draggable.data('product')); 

    $('#list_2_item_1').val(ui.draggable.data('product')); 
    $('#list_2_item_2').val(ui.draggable.data('product')); 
            $( "<li></li>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );
        }
    }).sortable({
        items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
        sort: function() {
            // gets added unintentionally by droppable interacting with sortable
            // using connectWithSortable fixes this, but doesn't allow you to customize active/hoverClass options
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-default" );
        }
    });
```

Comment: check your fiddle please. For me there's no drag an drop working at all in the example.

Comment: What are you using the `<input`>s for? In other words: if you're using them to submit a form, could you calculate the result when submitting, instead of with every update of the shopping list?

Comment: Only the end result will be submitted of course. I've put the stand-alone input fields in this questions only as an example =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you need to be able to create/update input fields dynamically when:

a) items are dragged and dropped from the items accordion to any of the carts

b) items are reordered within any of the carts (sortable)

Check this fiddle for the implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/CzKn9/3/

In your fiddle, i could see that you have used the same `id` property on multiple elements (2 elements with the `id` 'cart'). This is something you should look to avoid as the id attribute was designed to uniquely identify one element in the DOM tree. (for instance if you do a `document.getElementById('x')` and multiple elements have the id `'x'`, you'll get only the first element matching that ID). I modified your code to rectify this.

Secondly, I added a function that recreates your input fields (that will be submitted when you submit your form to server) on every drag and drop or sort event. The ids of the input fields created are of the form `list_1_item_1`, `list_1_item_2`, `list_2_item_1`, `list_1_item_2` and so on.

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

ID index increment added. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CzKn9/4/

Comment: Hey man there's something I need help with to finish making my form work.  How do I increment `list_1_item_1` to `list_1_item_2` for each item that gets added to the droppable list? Because right now all of the items in the list are `list_1_item_1`, even if you have 5 different items. The form will just accept the last item in the list this way.

Comment: I just realized that you stated that it does what I require in the last part of your answer, but in reality it's not working. Could you take a look for me?

Comment: sure. i'll fix that and get back to you.

Comment: Done. Please check the updated fiddle in my answer. I had missed out an `i++` there! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/5NWAQ/5/

Use the stop event of the sortable to retrieve the topmost li's value and add it to the input.

Comment: Nice job! The only problem is that it still fills out the entire form when the item is dragged to the cart. How can we fix this?

Comment: Look at http://jsfiddle.net/5NWAQ/8/ - you need to replace the $('#item_1') and $('#item_2') references with dynamic ones; I used a data-chart attribute to identiy the current sortable. Also watch you don't have html id attributes more than once! Further, you might use prependTo instead of appendTo, so the added item would automatically be at the top of the list after dragging. Don't be shy to accept answers either - people will be more likely to answer your questions in the future.

Comment: That's why I need help with this; my javascript is at beginner's level compared to my ruby on rails, html, css, etc. I barely understand the javascript syntax and know what functions are available to use.

I just want to get this problem to be solved I can implement it in my application. If you can do it in jsfiddle i'll accept your question :D

Comment: It doesn't add the data to the 2nd field though. It replaces the first field when another item is dropped instead of adding to the 2nd field.

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand what you want the input fields to behave like. I though they should hold the last item added to dropable 1, or 2, respectively.